# How to join two datasets using partially known column name?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

If I want to join two datasets by two known column names, `Petal.Width` and `Species` then we do

```
Joined <- left_join(iris, iris, by = join_by('Petal.Width', 'Species'), multiple = "all")
```

However, if I know one of the columns contains `Width` but do not know the full name, how do I join the datasets? I would expect a similar code shown in below

```
Joined <- left_join(iris, iris, by = join_by(contains('Width'), 'Species'), multiple = "all")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like this `left_join(iris, iris, by=c(grep("Width", colnames(iris), value=T), "Species"), relationship = "many-to-many")`?